# Approve This iPhone: Reset Protected Data

Tags: icloud, security

What data exactly is deleted when this option is selected? I am unable to access any other iOS device to approve my new iPhone so I am in a bind at the moment. I just don't want any of my important data to be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

I believe protected iCloud data are passwords, home, and health data.

The issue has now reared it's head on my computer. The following is copied from the help about the issue:
**"To keep your protected iCloud data secure-for example, passwords, home, and health data-you must authorize this Mac to use your iCloud account."**

I personally don't use any of those and am ready for them to be re-set. This has been a growing problem for me from one device to all one them over the past few months.

If it really is just that data then hopefully the reset will take care of the issue (I don't store that data anyway out of data privacy and security concerns).  This seems to have been happening since iOS 10. I had it for more than 6 months before this issue popped up for me.

When I did this on my phone and selected to reset protected data I got the following message to confirm the reset:
**"Passwords, home and other protected data stored in iCloud will be permanently deleted. You can't undo this action."**

- Keychain reset (don't use)
- No other messages popped up.

After doing the reset on my phone then I was requested (on my phone) to authorize my iPad and computer (two separate requests).  I entered my password, clicked allowed.  After turning off then on my iPad it resolved the issue on the iPad and computer.